# Laravel 5 Filesystem: Create a Folder in a Folder

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I'm programming a Filesystem Web App with Laravel at the moment and I can create folders and upload files. Now I want that when you are in a folder that you can create a new folder in the actual folder, so a folder in a folder.

Is there a way that you can save the actual path of the folder (maybe in a hidden text field or something) so the app know where you actual are and create a folder in a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you are in the folder `/foo/bar` in your app interface, you can reflect your current location in a URL parameter, for example.

Something like this:

```
http://localhost/filesystem.php?current_path=/foo/bar
```

or if you have the URL rewriting enabled on your server:

```
http://localhost/filesystem/foo/bar
```

Now, you just need to retrieve the `current_path` parameter value in your controller's method and use it as you want.

And when you click on the `baz` subfolder in `/foo/bar`, update your URL parameter: `...?current_path=/foo/bar/baz`. It's that simple.

Comment: I have already done this but the folder appears still in the main view.